# web scraping all universities with websites and description WHED website

Tags: python

anyone can help with scraping from https://www.whed.net/home.php
the code I'm using is giving me empty df. would love to have universities with websites and maybe field of study. My scraping skills are weak so if you can guide me through this would be great thanks guys.

```
begin=time.time()
countries=['Emirates','United States of America (all)']
result = [] # List to store all data
univ_links=[] # Links for all universities
fields = ['Street:','City:','Province:','Post Code:','WWW:','Fields of study:','Job title:'] 

webD = wb.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Sagasit\chromedriver.exe') # To launch chrome and run script
# Trigger the target website
webD.get("https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php")
webD.implicitly_wait(5)

#all_countries=[]
cntry_el = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Chp1"]/option')
#cntry_grp = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Chp1"]/optgroup')
grps=webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Chp1"]/optgroup/option[1]')
for c in cntry_el:countries.append(c.text)
for g in grps: countries.append(g.text)
    
for cntry in countries:
    select = Select(webD.find_element_by_id('Chp1'))#select country dropdown
    select.select_by_visible_text(cntry)#choosing country

    Btn_GO = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fsearch"]/p/input')
    Btn_GO.click()

    select_rpp = Select(webD.find_element_by_name('nbr_ref_pge'))#select results per page drop down
    select_rpp.select_by_visible_text('100')#choosing 100 results per page option

    university_form = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenu"]').find_element_by_id('results') 
    university_list = university_form.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/li') # list of university elements
    for univ in range(len(university_list)):
            href = university_list[univ].find_element_by_class_name('details').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0].get_property('href') # University details link
            univ_links.append(href)
    while True:
        try:
            webD.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next').click()
            university_form = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenu"]').find_element_by_id('results')
            university_list = university_form.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/li')
            for univ in range(len(university_list)):
                href = university_list[univ].find_element_by_class_name('details').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0].get_property('href') # University details link
                univ_links.append(href)
        except NoSuchElementException: break    
for l in univ_links:
    webD.get(l)
    webD.implicitly_wait(2)
    title=webD.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]').text
    title_detailed = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]').text
    cntry_name=webD.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenu"]/p[2]').text
    t1=webD.find_elements_by_class_name('dt') 
    t2=webD.find_elements_by_class_name('dd')        
    labels=webD.find_elements_by_class_name('libelle') 
    content=webD.find_elements_by_class_name('contenu') 
    temp={}
    fos=''
    fos1=''
    temp.update({'Title': title,'Detailed Title':title_detailed,'Country':cntry_name})
    for i in range(len(t1)):
        if t1[i].text == '' or t1[i].text == 'Address':
            continue 
        else:
            value=t2[i].text
            temp.update({t1[i].text:value.replace('\n',',')})
    for j in range(len(content)):
        if labels[j].text in fields:
            if labels[j].text == 'Fields of study:':
                info=content[j].text
                fos=fos+','+info
            elif labels[j].text == 'Job title:':
                info1=content[j].text
                fos1=fos1+','+info1
            else:
                key=labels[j].text
                temp.update({key[:-1]: content[j].text})
        
    temp.update({'Fields of study': fos.lstrip(','),'Job titles':fos1.lstrip(',')})
    result.append(temp)
data=pd.DataFrame(result)
data
end=time.time()
print("Time taken : "+ str(end-begin) +"s")
data.to_csv("WHED1.csv",index=False)
```

this code what i could use taken from github project.
would be great if i can re-create the data and save it, want this to be used as a dropdown in a web application just to make sure no mistakes written in the university studied in.

Comment: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Answer (score 0):

### Update 1/12/22 - Async

Found a much better solution using aiohttp, it also runs the entire list of countries in ~30 seconds instead of 3 hours

```
import json
import time
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


def main():
    print("Init")
    driver = init_driver()

    print("Opening Homepage")
    url = "https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)

    print("Gathering Countries")
    countries = get_countries(driver)
    driver.quit()

    print("Scraping")
    start = time.time()
    institution_list = asyncio.run(fetch_all(countries))

    print("Writing out")

    f = open('output.json', 'w')
    f.write(json.dumps(institution_list))
    f.close()
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Total time: {end - start}s")


def init_driver():
    chrome_executable = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', log_path='NUL')
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_executable, options=chrome_options)
    return driver


def get_countries(driver):
    select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "Chp1"))
    countries = list(map(lambda c: c.get_attribute('value'), select.options))
    countries.pop(0)
    return countries


def extract_institutions(html, country):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    page = soup.find('p', {'class': 'infos'}).text
    print(str(page))
    number_of_institutions = str(page).split()[0]
    if number_of_institutions == 'No':
        print(f"No results for {country}")
        return []

    results = []
    inst_index = 0

    raw = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'fancybox fancybox.iframe'})
    for i in raw:
        results.append({
            'name': str(i.text).strip(),
            'url': 'https://www.whed.net/' + str(i.attrs['href']).strip(),
            'country': country
        })

        inst_index += 1

    return {
        'country': country,
        'count': number_of_institutions,
        'records': results
    }


async def get_institutions(country, session):
    try:
        async with session.post(
            url='https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php',
            data={"Chp1": country, "nbr_ref_pge": 10000}
        ) as response:
            html = await response.read()
            print(f"Successfully got {country}")
            return extract_institutions(html, country)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unable to get {country} due to {e.__class__}.")


async def fetch_all(countries):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[get_institutions(country, session) for country in countries])


# Main call
main()
```

---

#### Old answer using synchronous algorithm

Improving on @Mithun's answer since it doesn't really work as it'll be stuck on the same page.

Also added direct access to the name and url to make it easier in case you want to access those.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

print("Init")

chrome_executable = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', log_path='NUL')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_executable, options=chrome_options)

print("Opening Homepage")
url = "https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

print("Selecting country")
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "Chp1"))
country = "Albania"
select.select_by_visible_text(country)
time.sleep(.5)

print("Searching")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Go']").click()
time.sleep(1)

print("Parsing")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

page = soup.find('p', {'class': 'infos'}).text

number_of_pages = str(page).split()[0]

counter = 10
results = []
while True:
    raw = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'fancybox fancybox.iframe'})
    for i in raw:
        results.append({
            'name': str(i.text).strip(),
            'url': 'https://www.whed.net/' + str(i.attrs['href']).strip(),
            'country': country
        })
        print(f'{len(results)}/{number_of_pages}')

    if counter >= int(number_of_pages):
        break
    counter += 10

    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Next page").click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
print(results)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Selenium to scrape data. The following code will help you scrape the university names for "United States of America (all)". Similarly, you can scrape for other countries as well using Loop or entering the name manually. If you need the field of study for every university, you can scrape its href using bs4 and its field of study.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "Chp1"))
select.select_by_visible_text("United States of America (all)")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Go']").click()
time.sleep(1)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
page = soup.find('p', {'class': 'infos'}).text
number_of_pages = str(page).split()[0]
counter = 10
while counter < int(number_of_pages):
    raw = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'details'})
    for i in raw:
        i = (str(i.text).lstrip())
        i = i.replace("\n","")
        i = i.replace("\r", "")
        i = i.replace("\t", "")
        print(i)
    next_page = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Next page").click()
    counter += 10
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your next_page never gets parsed, so the code loops only through the first page. Check my answer below.